# Conditional type based on value of other prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, toggle, react-props, react-typescript

In my project I have a component which takes two props:

```
collapsible,
onToggle
```

I struggle to create a type for these props in TypeScript. The problem is that when the collapsible is `true` I want the onToggle function to be a `(): void` but if collapsible is `false` I want the onToggle to be undefined.

I tried something like this:

```
type Props = {
  collapsible: boolean;
  onToggle: collapsible ? () => void : undefined;
}
```

But obviously it does not work, since the collapsible is undefined when defining onToggle type. How to deal with that? Is that even possible to have types depend on values?

Comment: do you really need `collapsible`? Can't you make `onToggle` optional, and check if `onToggle === undefined`?

Comment: Though this is kinda doable using discriminated union on boolean prop as in an answer below you are actually asking too much from the type system. Imagine having `collapsible: Math.random() > .5`

Comment: It was more general question if something like this is even possible. I know that in that case it is easy to just check it inside component :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a discriminated union  (discriminated on `collapsible`):

```
type Props = {
    common?: string
} & ({
    collapsible?: false;
    onToggle?: never;
} | {
    collapsible: true;
    onToggle: () => void
    })

function Test(p: Props) {
    return <></>
}

function Usage() {
    return <>
        <Test /> {/* Ok */}
        <Test collapsible={false} /> {/* Ok */}
        <Test collapsible={true} /> {/* Err, as expected */}
        <Test collapsible={true} onToggle={() => { }} /> {/* ok */}
    </>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoGATzCTgAUcwBnOAXjgG8K5e41cICADsA-AC44zGFGDCA5hQC+cAGRwAFN3J9+EADb6ULYACN9SCXEwp9zJAG5lcAD5cefAYePMzFyTIAro4evCIAKhDy8v6aAJTsAHxwAG4QwAAmoXBKcRQUmIHCGMAicOFI0hpgkowQLAnaukQwgVDCcAA8iZ0A9InK+eSFxTClHQCqzCjySBqN2S1tHd3Zup0V0nD9XL0AVHAA8gDWcHu9Smt8G5XwXkYm5khsnDZ2SCo7nPtHp+eXOl0102dwMD18TxeQQ+22S3wOAFEoFAADRwFCsJAAD1oGCQGTOFyuvBuW3uPj8z040JUESiMSp8ySXBynzhPwgfyJgJJ-UG5CAA)

Comment: This works great for the props in the `Usage` function. When you try to access the `onToggle` function inside the `Test` component, you will get the following error: `Property 'onToggle' does not exist on type 'Props'.
  Property 'onToggle' does not exist on type '{ common?: string | undefined; } & { collapsible?: false | undefined; }'`

Comment: To don't have the "Property 'onToggle' does not exist on type 'Props'" error, you must add the `onToggle` at the first conditional but as `never` type.

Answer (score 0):

Your collapsible prop is of boolean type, so it will either be false/true,

Can't you do something like this,

```
    type Props = {
     collapsible: boolean;
     onToggle():void | undefined;
   }
```

OR,

```
      type Props = {
         collapsible: boolean;
         onToggle?():void;
       }
```

And then while implementation, you can easily check that onToggle is undefined or not. Because if something is optional and not provided then it's undefined by default in TS.